# How to correctly predict using best model in talos

Tags: keras, hyperparameters, talos

I managed to use talos `scan` to generate model grid but I can't use the `evaluate` function

**SCANNING**

```
    t = talos.Scan(x=x,
                   y=y,
                   params=p,
                   shuffle=False,
                   x_val=x_val_multi,
                   y_val=y_val_multi,
                   model=sonos,
                   experiment_name='exp1',
                   disable_progress_bar=False,
                   print_params=False)
```

**EVALUATION**

```
e = Evaluate(t)
e.evaluate(x_val, 
                y_val,  
                model_id=None,
                folds=10,
                shuffle=True,
                metric='val_acc',
                asc=False,
                print_out=False)
```

but it keeps throwing

```
TypeError: evaluate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'task'
```

Answer (score 0):

Must specify **task** option with string argument.  Options are **binary**, **multi_class**, **multi_label**, and **continuous**

e.g.:

```
e = Evaluate(t)
e.evaluate(x_val, 
                y_val,  
                model_id=None,
                folds=10,
                shuffle=True,
                metric='val_acc',
                asc=False,
                print_out=False,
                task = 'binary')
```